# Android center CameraPreview on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am working on the face detection application for Android (my device is Nexus S with Android 4.1.2). My SurfaceView size is automatically set to 800x480 but my maximal camera resolution is 720x480. I have tried to change the size of SurfaceView in its onLayout() method which worked but then I was missing 80px in the preview. Is it possible to stretch or at least center the CameraPreview?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CameraPreview size can be changed using Camera.Parameters.
But I recommend that put the surfaceview on the center of screen.
Here's the code.
I didn't execute the code, but it may works.

```
// Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
final int width = r - l;
final int height = b - t;
if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
    final int surfaceViewWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
    surfaceView.layout((int)((width - surfaceViewWidth)*0.5), 0, (int)((width + surfaceViewWidth)*0.5), height);
} else {
    final int surfaceViewHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
    surfaceView.layout(0, (int)((height - surfaceViewHeight)*0.5), width, (int)((height + surfaceViewHeight)*0.5));
}
```

Comment: thanks, it wasn't the complete solution but it pointed me to the right direction: Sample projects -> Api demos -> graphics -> CameraPreview class. Now my problem is solved :]

Comment: I use a layout attribute to figure out my problem.
`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else runs into this issue - the way to center the camera preview is with a FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/surfacecontainer">
    <android.view.SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[More details can be found here](https://passospetits.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/camera-preview-sizes-in-android/).